# Combine firebase rules for facebook signin & normal sign up

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I need to combine the rules for firebase firestore. If I use the standard method,

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

the usual method of registering users with a username, email and password works, & everething is perfect, and everything suits me.
But the facebook login method stops working. Most likely due to the fact that the user is not yet logged in to the server but is already trying to write data to the users collection. As a result, I can see it in the list of authorized users, but in firestore, its email field remains nil. If I use the standard rule that allows everyone to write data from the Internet)(i know it's bad practice)

```
allow read, write: if true;
```

everything works fine. So I need to somehow add a rule that allows everyone to write data to my users collection? A trigger is used to create a document during registration

```
exports.createAccountDocument = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async user => {
  const { uid, displayName, email } = user
  const username = displayName;
  const profileImageUrl = uid;

const str = username;
const qwery = [];
for (let i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
    qwery[i] = str.substring(0, i + 1).replace(/\s/g, "").toLowerCase();
}
  const keywords = qwery;
  const bio = "";
  return await admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(uid)
    .set({ bio, keywords, email, profileImageUrl, uid, username })
})
```

Maybe it will be correct like this?

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
match /users/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true ;
    }
}
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code running in Cloud Functions using the server SDKs (including the Firebase Admin SDK) for Firestore always bypass security rules.  The code you're showing here in the onCreate trigger will always be able to write to Firestore regardless of what you write in your security rules.

Security rules only apply to direct access from web and mobile clients.  Your rules should focus on access controlled by Firebase Authentication.